# mobicents media server call recording

Tags: audio-recording, mobicents

Does Mobicents media server support call recording? When one calls call center, one would sometimes hear "The call will be recorded and monitored for quality purpose ...".  That's the call recording I am referring to

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does support recording. [RestComm](https://github.com/Mobicents/RestComm) is built on top of Mobicents SIP Servlets and the Mobicents Media Server and allows for easy call Recording, See how to create a voicemail application by example in less than 3 minutes https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S632Bna7VUc&list=PLGd7OD52_SoaFaobRX3eS1bsjpPa8deaR&index=4